# OpenConnection don't import full content

Tags: java, file-io

I want to import xml file from URL.

My code is:

```
URL url = new URL(partnersEntity.getUrl());

            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(55000);


            File file = new File(fileURL);


            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

            IOUtils.copy(urlConnection.getInputStream(), writer);
```

The problem is, that the XML file has 60000 lines, but my import saves only 11000 lines.

Where is the problem ?

Can i set content length ?

Comment: Do you have `writer.close()`?

Comment: Ok, that was the problem, thansk

Answer (score 0):

All input-output objects are resources which should be closed otherwise you will have resource leaks or lost unflushed buffers (your case). It should be done in the try-finally blocks. For your scenario:

```
URL url = new URL(partnersEntity.getUrl());
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(55000);

InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();    
try
{
    File file = new File(fileURL);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    try
    {
        IOUtils.copy(is, writer);
    }
    finally
    {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(writer);
    }
}
finally
{
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
}
```

In Java 7 you could use new try-syntax:

```
URL url = new URL(partnersEntity.getUrl());
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(55000);


File file = new File(fileURL);

try(
    InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
)
{
    IOUtils.copy(is, writer);
}
```